# how to wallet adapter still connect if i am change url

Tags: walletadapter

how to **wallet adapter** still connect if i am change **url** like "/" to "/dashboard"? what the best practice to save wallet connect.

Answer (score 1):

Solana wallet adapter provides `autoConnect` option which is what you need. Take a look at this [answer](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/3537/session-persistence-on-blockchain) for more instructions.